# How to move location of svg on iText PDF?

Tags: java, svg, itext

I tried to insert svg image to pdf file.

But I don't know how to move svg position on iText PDF.

The image is always located in (0,0).

How to move svg image position on iText PDF?

For example, I want to locate on the right side more than this sample.

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the example you mention:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate map = cb.createTemplate(6000, 6000);
drawSvg(map, CITY);
cb.addTemplate(map, 0, 0);
```

The `map` object is a canvas that in this case measures 6000 by 6000 user units (by default 1 user unit = 1 point).

This canvas can be used as a *Form XObject* inside the PDF. In iText language, a *Form XObject* is known as a `PdfTemplate` object. You draw the SVG to this `PdfTemplate`, in which case the coordinates defined in the SVG are used.

Once you have drawn the SVG to the canvas, you can add the *Form XObject* (or `PdfTemplate`) to the PDF using the `addTemplate()` method.

The first parameter is the object itself (in the snippet the `map` object), the two other parameters are the coordinates (in this case `(0, 0)` as you already mentioned in your question).

In short, you almost answered your own question: you refer to an example with the line:

```
cb.addTemplate(map, 0, 0);
```

And you notice that *The image is always located in (0,0).*

Change the `0, 0` in the `addTemplate()` method and you change the location of the SVG image in your PDF.